# How to create a hyperlink a new ASP.NET web form in a Webapplication

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am trying to add a new web form to an ASP.NET web application. However, wen I add a hyperlink to it from my main page, I get an IIS error. I am running it on localhost, i.e. my own machine without a web server. The hyperlink is:

```
<a href = "~/Products">Products</a>
```

I have a products folder and a products.aspx file in it.
My Solution Explorer window:

[image]

This is the IIS error I get:

[image]

Comment: Please consider adding the images directly to the question next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add **runat="server"** as well to resolve the dynamic starting location.

```
<a href = "~/Products/products.aspx" runat="server">Products</a>
```

This is needed so that ASP.NET CLR engine can dynamically update the path prior to delivering the final HTML code.

Comment: really?  Aren't you using webforms?  If you want to use "~", you'll have to use the runat="server"  attribute to make the ~ symbol  resolve to your localhost.  

Otherwise,  ASP.NET will hardcode the ~  into the URL.

Comment: Yeah, it worked! Sorry, VS crashed when I was compiling. I didn't notice and saw no changes in Firefox and thought it wasn't working.

Comment: Great! If this answer helps you, can you mark the question up as useful?    Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `"~/Products"` points to a directory rather to a file, thus your IIS complains that it is not allowed to show the contents of the directory.

Point to the file instead

```
<a href = "/Products/products.aspx">Products</a>
```

Comment: Yeah! This works! Thank you. But still, if I placed Products.aspx in the main directory, and linked it to `~/Products.aspx`, it still shows the forbidden error. And also, all the other files are linked as `~/Contacts` without referencing the file name with the '.aspx' extension.

Comment: Make sure your other resources, references *without* the `.aspx` are not like MVC routes or other resources that don't require the extension.

Answer (score 0):

I read that you moved Products.aspx page to the root of your site, but you're not able to display the page.

Try replacing the existing code with this.  And make sure runat="server" is included.

```
<a runat="server" href = "~/Products">Products</a>
```